# Move files based on content to different folders

Tags: powershell

What I have so far works from moving files with a certain content to a folder. I need to be able to move the remaining files to another folder "C:\Users\lawdv\Desktop\Pd-PC-Thermo\PDPA". I have tried If then Else statements but can't seems to get the syntax right.

```
Get-Childitem "C:\Users\lawdv\Desktop\Pd-PC-Thermo\ARC\" -filter *.ca2 -recurse | 
Select-String -List -Pattern "CP2023" |
Move-Item -Destination "C:\Users\lawdv\Desktop\Pd-PC-Thermo\CP"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Where-Object` to filter the files based on what `Select-String` finds (or doesn't find):

```
Get-Childitem ... |Where-Object { $_ |Select-String CP2023 |Select -First 1 } |Move-Item ...
```

Comment: That works for moving to files that meet the condition but how do I get the files that don't to move to another destination?

Comment: @DavidVLawson use the `-not` operator: `Get-Childitem ... |Where-Object { -not($_ |Select-String CP2023 |Select -First 1) }`